# How does Dropwizard know how to serialize Joda DateTime objects, and how can I modify it?

Tags: java, jodatime, dropwizard

I'm looking at a REST API which uses DropWizard. DropWizard appears to somehow magically know how to serialize joda DateTime objects to a string formatted like this:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

But if I write a test which uses an ObjectMapper to serialize a joda DateTime object, I get something like:

```
{"month_of_year":1,"hour_of_day":0,"minute_of_hour":15,"second_of_minute":3,"millis_of_second":0,"week_of_weekyear":3,"weekyear":2018,"year_of_era":2018,"year_of_century":18,"century_of_era":20,"millis_of_day":903000,"second_of_day":903,"minute_of_day":15,"day_of_year":18,"day_of_week":4,"day_of_month":18,"year":2018,"era":1,"millis":1516259703000,"chronology":{"zone":{"uncached_zone":{"cachable":true,"fixed":false,"id":"America/Denver"},"fixed":false,"id":"America/Denver"}},"zone":{"uncached_zone":{"cachable":true,"fixed":false,"id":"America/Denver"},"fixed":false,"id":"America/Denver"},"after_now":true,"before_now":false,"equal_now":false}
```

How does DropWizard know how to serialize this?

The field I'm serialized is annotated like this:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
DateTime myDate;
```

I understand that I'm supplying a format string there, but I'd like to understand why `ObjectMapper` (in my test) doesn't respect it, while DropWizard does. (The annotation is a Jackson annotation, not a DropWizard one, so it confuses me that `ObjectMapper.writeValue()` wouldn't respect it).

When looking at the source of the `@JsonFormat` annotation, I see:

```
/**
 * Datatype-specific additional piece of configuration that may be used
 * to further refine formatting aspects. This may, for example, determine
 * low-level format String used for {@link java.util.Date} serialization;
 * however, exact use is determined by specific <code>JsonSerializer</code>
 */
public String pattern() default "";
```

This leads me to believe that Jackson doesn't actually supply the `JsonSerializer` that recognizes this `pattern` attribute, and at the same time leads me to believe that DropWizard does have such a `JsonSerializer`. How can I configure/modify/override the `JsonSerializer` that DropWizard is apparently using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test is not using the right `ObjectMapper`. DW in its bootstrap will configure the `ObjectMapper` for you with reasonable defaults (that's DW's whole thing - everything is somewhat reasonable and pre-configured).

So, in your case, your test would need to use `Jackson.newObjectMapper()`. Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

    ObjectMapper myMapper=  new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectMapper dwMapper = Jackson.newObjectMapper();
    System.out.println(myMapper.writeValueAsString(new X()));
    System.out.println(dwMapper.writeValueAsString(new X()));
}

public static class X { 
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
}
```

Will print:

```
{"now":{"era":1,"dayOfYear":18,"dayOfWeek":4,"dayOfMonth":18,"year":2018,"weekOfWeekyear":3,"millisOfDay":37615193,"monthOfYear":1,"hourOfDay":10,"minuteOfHour":26,"secondOfMinute":55,"millisOfSecond":193,"weekyear":2018,"yearOfEra":2018,"yearOfCentury":18,"centuryOfEra":20,"secondOfDay":37615,"minuteOfDay":626,"zone":{"fixed":false,"uncachedZone":{"cachable":true,"fixed":false,"id":"Europe/London"},"id":"Europe/London"},"millis":1516271215193,"chronology":{"zone":{"fixed":false,"uncachedZone":{"cachable":true,"fixed":false,"id":"Europe/London"},"id":"Europe/London"}},"afterNow":false,"beforeNow":true,"equalNow":false}}
{"now":"2018-01-18 10:26:55"}
```

And for completeness, these are the modules that are registered for you:

```
private static ObjectMapper configure(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        mapper.registerModule(new GuavaModule());
        mapper.registerModule(new LogbackModule());
        mapper.registerModule(new GuavaExtrasModule());
        mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
        mapper.registerModule(new AfterburnerModule());
        mapper.registerModule(new FuzzyEnumModule());
        mapper.registerModules(new Jdk8Module());
        mapper.registerModules(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new AnnotationSensitivePropertyNamingStrategy());
        mapper.setSubtypeResolver(new DiscoverableSubtypeResolver());

        return mapper;
    }
```

These are all overwritable in the bootstrap.

Please not that I might be on an older version of DW, so it might be slightly different in the latest.

Artur